# How to use parameter splatting when piping to ForEach-Object?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use splatting at the pipeline, passing to `ForEach-Object`. Example code below:

```
$arr = @(
    @{
        Path = "C:\Folder1"
        Recurse = $true
    },
    @{
        Path = "C:\Folder2"
        Recurse = $true
    }
)

foreach ($obj in $arr) {
    Get-ChildItem @obj
}
# Working OK.

# Now use splatting with ForEach-Object:
$arr | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem @$_ }
# Not working.
```

I have also tried: `Get-ChildItem @($_)` which does not work.

The error message is:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\System.Collections.Hashtable' because it does not exist.
```

Comment: Splatting works by using `@` *instead of* `$`, so try `Get-ChildItem @_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell's [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)**, which enables passing arguments (parameter values) to commands via [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (*named* arguments) or, less commonly, [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) (*positional* arguments):

- requires the hashtable / array to be **stored in a *variable*** (e.g. `$foo`), ahead of time.
- must **reference that variable with symbol `@` *instead of* `$`** (e.g. `@foo`, *not* <del>`@$foo`</del>).

Therefore, use `@_` in your case to splat via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_):

```bash
$arr | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem @_ } # !! @_, not @$_
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to *omit* the `$` from the variable name when splatting:

```
$arr | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem @_ }
```